# How to display error message from exception without redirecting to new view in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to catch exceptions that might bubble up from a class library method to the action from which it was called and would like to display the error in the view without actually redirecting to a new view.  I've overriden the OnException method in my controller and have created a partial view to display the error but when an error occurs the partial view is not being rendered where I want it to show but rather where I have a table and it will be replaced with the error message which is not what I wan, not to mention the table is in a different place in the view than where the error should display.  I haven't done much exception handling with MVC so I don't know if my approach is completely wrong.

My code for the exception

```
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var exp = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        //Assigns error message to property for message in view model
        ReceivngFormViewModel viewModel = new ReceivngFormViewModel
        {
            ErrorMessage = exp.Exception.Message
        };

        filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            //_Error is the partial view
            ViewName = "_Error",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewModel)
        };
    }
```

Comment: What is happening with the above code ? I do not see any code which does redirection !

Answer (score 0):

```
this code help you use ModelState.AddModelError  
**Controller**
Model obj=new Model();
     try{

    }
    cathch(exception ex){
    ModelState.AddModelError("objectname", ex.tostring());
    }
    return obj;
    **Viwe**
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.objectname)
```

Comment: This doesn't help, it does the same thing as the code I've been using, it erases my table and puts the error message where my table used to be instead of where I specify the partial view to be.